# How to check Amazon product it can be sold or needs an approval using MWS API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to check amazon products based on ASIN so some one input an ASIN code and API will tell it that this product can be sold or not or it needs approval to sell ?

Is there any one who did this before ? please guide me for this,

Thanks

Comment: I tried ItemLookup() of AWS API and GetMatchingProduct() of MWS API but no information found in their responses

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no API functionality to view this.

You can maybe make it slightly easier by linking directly to this link and replacing the ASIN each time in your UI: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/productsearch?q=B000ASDFCC then you click just click Listing limitations apply to see.

[image]

Comment: Yes i know that but issue is this needs to be logged in first and we have thousands of ASINs and want to check using a script which will run automatically on define time interval on daily basis. @iMakeWebsites